# How to iterate over facts in Ansible

Tags: windows, syntax, ansible, yaml

I'm new in Ansible and I find my self trying to extract info from win_disk_facts. This module generates a objec that collect a json whit info of all disk presents in the server. I need only few atributes of this object, like size, letter, etc. but I dont know how to iterate over it.

What I want to do is something like (in python syntax)

```
foreach(disk in disks):
    print(disk.number)
    print(disk.size)
    print(disk.freeSpace)
```

thx a lot

Comment: This is what is called a loop in about every programming language or management tool. Typing "ansible loop" in your favorite search engine should give as a first result: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html. Note that "python loop", "java loop", "chef loop".... should give very pertinent results as well if you ether need that for something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with_items` such this example:

```
- name: "loop through list from a disks variable"
  debug:
     msg: "Disk details: number: {{ item.number }}, size: {{ item.size }}, freeSpace: {{ item.freeSpace }}"
  with_items: "{{ disks }}"
```